# SQLite and LevelDB - Discrepancy in Wiki?

Tags: sqlite, browser, leveldb

Embedded databases in web browsers give 2 main names - SQLite and LevelDB but it is unclear that which is underlying database for Google Chrome.

[Wiki for SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) - "The browsers ***Google Chrome***, Opera, Safari and the Android Browser all allow for storing information in, and *retrieving it from, a SQLite database within the browser*...."

[Wiki for LevelDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) - "LevelDB is used as the *backend database for **Google Chrome's** IndexedDB* and is one of the supported backends for Riak."

This looks like a discrepancy in Wiki information because it is unclear that which database is used for storage in Google's Chrome.

FireFox certainly uses SQLite as embedded database but there is no concrete information on which is underlying embedded database for Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari.

Wiki of SQLite does say that SQLite is underlying embedded database for Opera and Safari but is it sure? And then what about IE?

Comment: @Dan - Why a web browser will use 2 underlying embedded databases? And is there any reference over web which give this information? I couldn't find any information. And what about underlying embedded database for FireFox, IE, Opera and Safari.

Comment: There are two database APIs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API  In Chrome, which implements both, the former uses SQLite and the latter LevelDB.

Comment: @DanD. - Thank you for your inputs. Do you know which all are the underlying databases for IE and Android browser. I have opened another discussion with much broader context - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220099/websql-and-indexeddb-performance