# IndexedDB - Discrepancy in information by Mozilla

Tags: mozilla, indexeddb, offline-caching, embedded-database, offline-storage

I found 2 different references about IndexedDB in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) website.

Statement 1:  *"IndexedDB is an API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data"*

Statement 2:   "*IndexedDB is a transactional database system, like a SQL-based RDBMS;*"

If I am correct then IndexedDB is a database API for underlying browser embedded database, like LevelDB for Chrome.

It is important to understand what IndexedDB, if want to look from performance perspective - [IndexedDB Performance and IndexedDB v/s WebSQL performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220099/websql-and-indexeddb-performance)

Comment: So ............. what's the question? Is this linked to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220099/websql-and-indexeddb-performance/29241658#29241658

Comment: Maybe start with reading the specs on w3c (http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) This will be more correct than what you find on Mozilla. Ofc this is more technical and is a bit harder to read :)

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest  - Thank you for your inputs. My point is that information on a official web site seems to be correct. It is paramount to understand that whether IndexedDB is a database API or database itself. As per my understanding, IndexedDB is database API.

Comment: @KristofDegrave - Thank you for your inputs. As per my understanding, IndexedDB is database API. I just wanted to bring it for discussion and consideration if Mozilla information is actually correct or if I am missing something.

Comment: I think they wanted to point out that indexeddb is transactional and they refer to RDBMS because all RDBMS are transactional since they implement the ACID principal

Comment: @KristofDegrave - Makes sense but if we read the complete statement then it says - "IndexedDB is a transactional database system, like a SQL-based RDBMS; however whereas the latter uses tables with fixed columns, IndexedDB is a JavaScript-based object-oriented database." So, it is apparent that they are referring IndexedDB as DBMS but if I am correct then it is API to access underlying browser embedded database system. So, to me referring IndexedDB as DBMS looks incorrect and controversial. Isn't it ?

Comment: Like you say you can't compare indexedb with a DBMS because indexeddb API uses the NoSQL approch. But it works transactional.